# Key error in dictionary. How to make Python print my dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.4

In my homework, this question is asking me to make a function where Python should create dictionary of how many words that start with a certain letter in the long string is symmetrical. Symmetrical means the word starts with one letter and ends in the same letter. I do not need help with the algorithm for this. I definitely know I have it right, but however I just need to fix this Key error that I cannot figure out. I wrote `d[word[0]] += 1`, which is to add 1 to the frequency of words that start with that particular letter.

The output should look like this (using the string I provided below):
`{'d': 1, 'i': 3, 't': 1}`

```
t = '''The sun did not shine
it was too wet to play
so we sat in the house
all that cold cold wet day

I sat there with Sally
we sat there we two
and I said how I wish
we had something to do'''

def symmetry(text):
    from collections import defaultdict
    d = {}
    wordList = text.split()
    for word in wordList:
        if word[0] == word[-1]:
            d[word[0]] += 1
    print(d)
print(symmetry(t))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to increase the value of an entry which has yet to be made resulting in the `KeyError`. You could use `get()` for when there is no entry for a key yet; a default of `0` will be made (*or any other value you choose*). With this method, you would not need `defaultdict` (*although very useful in certain cases*).

```
def symmetry(text):
    d = {}
    wordList = text.split()
    for word in wordList:
        key = word[0]
        if key == word[-1]:
            d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + 1
    print(d)
print(symmetry(t))
```

**Sample Output**

```
{'I': 3, 'd': 1, 't': 1}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct way to do it! It worked! Hopefully I won't get key errors in the future by using your code (the part that you corrected from mine)

Answer (score 1):

You never actually use `collections.defaultdict`, although you import it. Initialize `d` as `defaultdict(int)`, instead of as `{}`, and you're good to go.

```
def symmetry(text):
    from collections import defaultdict
    d = defaultdict(int)
    wordList = text.split()
    for word in wordList:
        if word[0] == word[-1]:
            d[word[0]] += 1
    print(d)

print(symmetry(t))
```

Results in:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'I': 3, 't': 1, 'd': 1})
```